# Angular not apply changes after reopen parent component with routerLink

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services, angular2-observables

I have 1 component named "parent" and another called child (contained in the route) "child", when I go back to the parent component using [routerLink] = "['']" previously loaded variables are not displayed in the component html.

Code in Component Parent:

```
categories: ProductCategory[];
ngOnInit ()
{
  meuServico.getProductCategories().subscribe(
    categories 
    =>  {
        this.categories = categories;
        console.log(this.categories);
        ...
        optional setTimeout (for tests)
        ...
    }
  )
}
```

Parent Component HTML Code:

```
<div *ngFor="let category of categories"><br>
    <a>{{ category.name }}</a>   
</div>
```

Child Component HTML code:

```
<div class="test-purposes" [routerLink]="['']"</div>;
```

Important information:
when I put this code inside the component in the inscription:

```
setTimeout (
() => {
    log (categories)
}, 1000);
```

The result of the console.log inside the setTimeout is undefined but the first console.log (outside the setTimeout = real-time) contains the correct result.

Important information:
The HTML and also the console log within setTimeout are not appearing after reopening the routerLink in the child component where, it redirects to the parent component

Important information:
Before the reopen (first call without any routerLink and subscription) component works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to the providers in the component and module and also to the observable, I have already solved

Answer (score 0):

```
categories: ProductCategory[];
ngOnInit ()
{
  meuServico.getProductCategories().subscribe(
    categories 
    =>  {
        this.categories = categories;
        console.log(this.categories);
        ...
        optional setTimeout (for tests)
        ...
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21587483)